# JS Regex требуется помощь

Tags: javascript

Я не сильно в regex и это моя проблема. Помогите составить пожалуйста, чтобы в конце строки в обязательном порядке было слово `production` после тире...

То есть, `(любое 1 слово)-production.(расширение любое)`

Comment: Вы пишете "в конце строки" однако после production у вас идет .(расширение любое).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот несколько вариантов:

`.*-production` - любое количество любых символов, за которыми следует -production

`.+-production` - один или более любых символов, за которыми следует -production

`\w*-production` -  любое количество букв, цифр или _ за которыми следует -production

`[a-z]+-production` - слово из 1 или более букв a-z за которыми следует -production

Если надо, чтобы -production завершало строку - добавьте в конце к каждому выражению $